# N1QL couchbase query - Update array within a dynamic JSON object. (Removing an element of array nested inside Json object)

Tags: arrays, json, couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to write an N1QL update query. I want to delete those objects from array whose “vs” value is something, let’s say “k_a”.
This is my sample document.

```
{
  "ADD": {
    "k_2": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_a"
      },
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_d"
      }
    ],
    "k_9": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_f"
      },
      {
        "allowed": true,
        "vs": "k_a"
      }
    ]
  },
  "REMOVE": {
    "k_4": [
      {
        "allowed": true,
        "vs": "k_a"
      }
    ],
    "k_7": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_g"
      },
      {
        "allowed": true,
        "vs": "k_a"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have already tried this query -

```
UPDATE bucket_name sp
    SET obj = ARRAY v FOR v IN obj WHEN v.vs != "k_a" END
    FOR obj IN OBJECT_VALUES(sp.ADD) END WHERE META(sp).id = "SPT|O|789"
```

but probably I'm doing something wrong.

This is the document I'm expecting after update -

```
{
  "ADD": {
    "k_2": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_d"
      }
    ],
    "k_9": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_f"
      }
    ]
  },
  "REMOVE": {
    "k_4": [],
    "k_7": [
      {
        "allowed": false,
        "vs": "k_g"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note - Here the keywords “ADD” and “REMOVE” are static but anything of the form “k_number” or “k_letter” is dynamic, and can be anything.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Where clause controls if the document must mutate or not. SET clause controls what to mutate. You need the where clause to avoid unnecessary mutation (Example: If repeat same update second time there should not be any update, i.e mutation count should be 0 unless some one changed the document.).

```
UPDATE sourceprioritization sp USE KEYS "SPT|O|789"
    SET sp.[obj1.name].[obj.name] = ARRAY v FOR v IN obj.val WHEN v.vs != "k_a" END
    FOR obj IN OBJECT_PAIRS(obj1.val)
           FOR obj1 IN OBJECT_PAIRS(sp) WHEN obj1.name IN ["ADD", "REMOVE"] AND "k_a" IN obj.val[*].vs END
WHERE ANY obj1 IN OBJECT_PAIRS(sp) SATISFIES obj1.name IN ["ADD", "REMOVE"]
      AND (ANY obj IN OBJECT_PAIRS(obj1.val) SATISFIES "k_a" IN obj.val[*].vs END) END;
```

OR

```
UPDATE sourceprioritization sp USE KEYS "SPT|O|789"
    SET obj1.val.[obj.name] = ARRAY v FOR v IN obj.val WHEN v.vs != "k_a" END
    FOR obj IN OBJECT_PAIRS(obj1.val)
           FOR obj1 IN OBJECT_PAIRS(sp) WHEN obj1.name IN ["ADD", "REMOVE"] AND "k_a" IN obj.val[*].vs END
WHERE ANY obj1 IN OBJECT_PAIRS(sp) SATISFIES obj1.name IN ["ADD", "REMOVE"]
      AND (ANY obj IN OBJECT_PAIRS(obj1.val) SATISFIES "k_a" IN obj.val[*].vs END) END;
```